# Remove leading zeroes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example I have such a data frame

```
import pandas as pd
nums = {'amount': ['0324','S123','0010', None, '0030', 'SA40', 'SA24']}
df = pd.DataFrame(nums)
```

[image]

And I need to remove all leading zeroes and replace NONEs with zeros:

[image]

I did it with cycles but for large frames it works not fast enough.
I'd like to rewrite it using vectores

Comment: How about if only a single `0` ?   Keep it or wipe it to blank ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```py
df['amount'].str.replace(r'^(0+)', '').fillna('0')
```

```
0     324
1    S123
2      10
3       0
4      30
5    SA40
6    SA24
Name: amount, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

I see already nice answer from @Epsi95 though, you even can try with character set with `regex`

```
>>> df['amount'].str.replace(r'^[0]*', '', regex=True).fillna('0')
0     324
1    S123
2      10
3       0
4      30
5    SA40
6    SA24
```

### Explanation:

```
^[0]*

^ asserts position at start of a line
Match a single character present in the list below [0]
* matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.lstrip('0').fillna(value='0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step :

**Remove all leading zeros:**

Use `str.lstrip` which returns a copy of the string with leading characters removed (based on the string argument passed).

Here,

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.lstrip('0')
```

For more, (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lstrip)

**Replace None with zeros:**

Use `fill.na` which works with others than `None` as well

Here,

```
df['amount'].fillna(value='0')
```

And for more : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

**Result in one line:**

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.lstrip('0').fillna(value='0')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you need to ensure single `0` or the last `0` is not removed, you can use:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace(r'^(0+)(?!$)', '', regex=True).fillna('0')
```

Regex `(?!$)` ensure the matching substring (leading zeroes) does not including the last `0`.  Thus, effectively keeping the last `0`.

### Demo

**Input Data**

```
nums = {'amount': ['0324','S123','0010', None, '0030', 'SA40', 'SA24', '0', '000']}
df = pd.DataFrame(nums)

  amount
0   0324
1   S123
2   0010
3   None
4   0030
5   SA40
6   SA24
7      0           <==   Added a single 0 here
8    000           <==   Added a sequence of all 0's here
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

  amount
0    324
1   S123
2     10
3      0
4     30
5   SA40
6   SA24
7      0           <==  Single 0 is not removed  
8      0           <==  Last 0 is kept
```